# c++ How to use concepts to check that the passed type has a specific method

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a class:

```
template<typename T, typename Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class CCircucarBuffer {
 private:
  size_t size_ = 0;
  T* values_;
  Alloc alloc_;
};
```

I need to verify that the Alloc type being passed has allocate() and deallolate() methods.

I know it can be done with concepts in c++20, but I can't find how

Comment: no, i didn't try

Comment: Note: you don't _need_ to verify it. From the definition of `CCircucarBuffer` you can directly call `Alloc::allocate()` which will lead to a compilation error if the function does not exist. A concept will help you provide better error messages though. Is it your need?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to see a 200 line error message

Comment: @teddy_bear But why not?  The longer the error message the better!  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most basic version possible is just this:

```cpp
template<typename A>
concept Alloc = requires(A a)
{
    {a.allocate()};
};
```

Note it does not check `allocate`'s return type nor does it care if it's static or not; all it does is check if `allocate` is callable with object of type A.
I guess the one extra line for `deallocate` is a low hanging fruit now ;)

```cpp
template<typename A>
concept Alloc = requires(A a)
{
    {a.allocate()};
};

template<Alloc A>
void foo(A a)
{
    a.allocate();
}

struct HasAllocate
{
    void allocate() {}
};

struct HasStaticAllocate
{
    static void allocate() {}
};

struct NoAllocate
{

};

int main()
{
    foo(HasAllocate{});
    foo(HasStaticAllocate{});
    // foo(NoAllocate{}); //compilation error here  
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9xn95Tj6v

Comment: is there a reason to wrap the `a.allocate()` in curly braces in the concept definition ?

Comment: @LorahAttkins  they start to matter when expression type comes into play, e.g. `{a.allocate()} -> std::same_as<void>;`. In this particular snippet, it's just my preference to write them ;)